# load dynamic content with ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to load a content by ajax
i got this

```
<nav>
<ul class="menu-principal links-to-floor">
<li class="logo-principal"><img src="images/plastico-logo.png" alt=""></li>
<li class=""><a href="contacto.html" data-id="#contacto" class="btn-secciones">Contacto</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="la-agencia.html" data-id="#laagencia" class="btn-secciones">La Agencia</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="portafolio.html" data-id="#portafolio" class="btn-secciones">Portafolio</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="blog.html" data-id="#blog" class="btn-secciones">Blog</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and the content

```
<div id="ascensorBuilding">
<div class="floor floor-1 home-inicio"></div>
<div class="floor floor-2 contentarea"><span class="text">content1</span></div>
<div class="floor floor-3 contentarea"><span class="text">content2</span></div>
<div class="floor floor-4 contentarea"><span class="text">content3</span></div>
<div class="floor floor-5 contentarea"><span class="text"content 4</span></div>
</div>
```

and this is my jquery code

```
$(".btn-secciones").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    secciones = $('.btn-secciones').attr('data-id');
    seccion_actual = $('.btn-secciones').attr('href');
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: seccion_actual,
            cache:false,
            success: function callme(html){
            document.querySelector('.contentarea').innerHTML=html; 
            },
          dataType: "html"
        });
     $(".btn-secciones").css("color","black");
     console.log($(this).data('id'));
});
```

the problem is only load the first content
what i doing wrong?

Comment: you can try $(".contentarea").load(seccion_actual);

Comment: I noted that your HTML file has unclosed tag. After floor5

Comment: <div id="ascensorBuilding"> <div class="floor floor-1 home-inicio"></div> <div class="floor floor-2 contentarea"><span class="text"> </span></div> <div class="floor floor-3 contentarea"><span class="text">content2</span></div> <div class="floor floor-4 contentarea"><span class="text">content3</span></div> <div class="floor floor-5 contentarea"><span class="text">content 4</span></div> </div> I closed the last <span>

Comment: When you say that it only loads the first content, what do you mean exactly? The `querySelector` method only returns the first element found, so you will only be putting the content in one of the elements, is that what you mean? Regardless of which button you click, that content will end up in the first content area, is that what you mean?

Comment: i have to load 5 diferent content, but, only is loading the first content, the other content doesnt loads